# Delete all files which contain a string & is a specific size in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need a script that looks at a directory, select the ones that has a string in its content and is "8" in length(size).

I've tried to do this like that, but somehow it doesn't work. Any tips?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 8 } | Select-String -pattern "foo" | group path | select name  | foreach-object {remove-item $_.name}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to with group-object here, from what you've explained that is not necessary. As written, you also need to remember that the current directory may not be `c:\test` so you need to use `$_.fullname` for the remove.

I think you mean to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 8 -and $_.name -match "foo"} | foreach-object {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

Comment: I don't want to match the name "foo" with the file name. I need to delete the files that contain "foo" string.

Comment: Does the length of the string your trying to match equal 8, or you only want to look for that string in files where the file size is 8 bytes? Did you make any attempt yourself to modify what has been shared so far? Just trying to help you have a better understanding of how this can be done.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that my script actually worked. My first file was 8 bytes in size but the second test I did was 11 for some reason, when I changed the size to 11 it just worked fine. Thanks for your help and yes, I wanted to delete files that contain a specific string "foo" and is "8" bytes in size.